# Legend; text/description before key/colour?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

By default MATLAB puts the text part of a legend entry *after* the sample of what is used in the plot. Is there any way to reverse this? For example, using the below code the first entry in the legend is a dark blue rectangle followed by the text `I'm`; I'd like it to be the other way around (i.e. the text `I'm` followed by a dark blue rectangle). I am using R2017b

Example code:

```
test_values = [ 12, 232, 22, 44, 67, 72, 123, 35, 98 ];
test_text   = [ "I'm", "sorry", "Dave", "I'm", "afraid", "I", "can't", "do", "that" ];

Pie = pie( test_values );

legend( test_text );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative solution based on the approach used by EBH in his solution.

I hope it will not be considered a plagiarism, in case I apologise, please, put a comment and I'll delete my answer.

The solution I propose does not use any undocumented feature and has been tested on R2015b; I do not know if it will work on later Releases.

The idea is:

- call the `legend` function by requiring all the output paramentes
- work on the second output parameter
- the first half of data in this parameter are the ones of the `text` of the legend
- the second half are the adta of the `patch` of the legend (the boxes)
- loop over this parameter
- Get the original position of the text item
- Get the original coordinated of the Vertices of the patch
- Set the position of the text to the original coordinate of the first `X` of the patch
- Set the "X" coordinates of the patch to the original "X" position of the text and scale it

The last step contains a drawbak, because it requires to scale the size of the patchs to hold them inside the legend box.

Also, I've modified the definition of the text of the legend since R2015b does not handle the string as per in the question.

```
test_values = [ 12, 232, 22, 44, 67, 72, 123, 35, 98 ];
test_text   = { 'I''m', 'sorry', 'Dave', 'I''m', 'afraid', 'I' 'can''t', 'do', 'that' };

Pie = pie( test_values );
% get all the output from the legend function
[lgd,icons,plots,txt]=legend( test_text );
% Get the number of elements in the legend
n_items=length(icons)/2
% Loop over the legend's items
for i=1:n_items
   % Get the original position of the text item
   orig_txt=icons(i).Position
   % Get the original coordinated of the Vertices of the patch
   orig_mark=icons(i+n_items).Vertices
   % Set the position of the text to the original coordinate of the first
   % "X" of the patch
   icons(i).Position=[orig_mark(1) orig_txt(2)]
   % Set the "X" coordinates of the patch to the original "X" position of
   % the text and scale it
   icons(i+n_items).Vertices(:,1)=icons(i+n_items).Vertices(:,1)+orig_txt(1)*.7
end
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I wanted to avoid calling `legend` with four outputs as [Mathworks say it is not recommended](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html?s_tid=doc_ta#mw_ee02d6fe-d9f3-4819-98b3-11744cb51634), and it has some [unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214559/setting-a-title-for-a-legend-in-matlab). But this is by no means plagiarism.

Comment: I've tested this and it works perfectly (thank you!) and hits everything I asked for. I've accepted this answer as it feels the most eloquent/simplest of the two (both fantastic) methods posted that solve the problem.

Comment: Happy I've been of help to you

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option using some [undocumented features](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-legend-customization):

```
test_values = [ 12, 232, 22, 44, 67, 72, 123, 35, 98 ];
test_text   = {'I''m'; 'sorry'; 'Dave'; 'I''m';'afraid';'I';'can''t';'do';'that'};
Pie = pie( test_values );
leg = legend(test_text,'Location','eastoutside');
drawnow % without this you can't accsses the legend entries
icons = [leg.EntryContainer.NodeChildren.Icon]; % an array with all the legend icons
leg.ItemTokenSize(1) = 0; % set the relative position of the text in the legend to x=0

% the following will probably need some fine tuning for a specific
% figure. It shifts the icons positions horizontally (i.e. only the first
% row has values other than zeros):
shift = [10    10     17     17
         0     0     0     0
         0     0     0     0];
for k = 1:numel(icons)
    % move the icon (patch) border:
    icons(k).Transform.Children.Children(1).VertexData = ...
    icons(k).Transform.Children.Children(1).VertexData+shift;
    % move the icon (patch) fill:
    icons(k).Transform.Children.Children(2).VertexData = ...
    icons(k).Transform.Children.Children(2).VertexData+shift;
end

% the following will probably need some fine tuning for a specific
% figure. It expands the legend box horizontally:
shift = [0    0     1     1
         0     0     0     0
         0     0     0     0];
leg.BoxEdge.VertexData = leg.BoxEdge.VertexData+shift; % the box border
leg.BoxFace.VertexData = leg.BoxFace.VertexData+shift; % the box face
```

[image]

Comment: I've posted an answer based on your approach with the difference that it does not use any undocumented feature. I hope you will not consider it as plagiarism. Should you, inseted, consider it as such, I apologise and, please, let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: This works perfectly; thank you very much. However, I've accepted a different answer as I feel it built on this and makes it a bit simpler (/ more eloquent); however that's not a slight on this answer! (If I could have accepted two answers I would!)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible, but you can workaround to get there if you give legend empty text and then display text outside, something like this:

```
figure;
Pie = pie( test_values );
emptyLegend = repmat({''},9,1);
h = legend( emptyLegend );
text(repmat(0.8,9,1),[0.8:-0.1:0]',test_text)
set(h,'Position',[0.9 0.5 0.05 0.35])
```

Comment: So I tested this and it looks like it's the starting point of a solution but not quite there. For me at least (not sure if it's the same for everyone) the text is moved but not the sample; similarly, the text isn't in the right location so would need some manual adjusting or further work to make it work for any setup.